# How to add a CSS specifc for Google Chrome?

Tags: html, css, frontend

I need to add a css code that only applies to google chrome but not to firefox.

**Problem:** I want to put a border-bottom to a div with a class of .div-special

```
 .div-special{
      border-bottom: 1px solid #c8c8c8;
 }
```

**Output:** The border bottom should only apply for google chrome browser but not to firefox.

Please help me.

Comment: try to detect user agent with javascript. But user agent can be spoofed easily.

Comment: What you'll need is $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']

Comment: Prefer feature detection. [Use modernizr for that](http://modernizr.com).  [There are several fun ways of going about it](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/issues/299).

Comment: And why do you want to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) { 
 .div-special{
      border-bottom: 1px solid #c8c8c8;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    .class{color:red;}
}

/* Safari only override */
::i-block-chrome,.class {
 color:blue;
}}
```

**OR**

```
@media all and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) and (min-resolution: .001dpcm) {
    .class {
       color:red;
    }
}
```

JQuery using User Agent

```
if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1) {
    $('.container').hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
   // your CSS here
}
```